# Subversion trunk as DocumentRoot of website

Tags: linux, svn, website, repository

We have subversion running on our Linux development server

Can the repository be located in the DocumentRoot of a Virtual host say /var/www/ourwebsite?

If I create the repository in there, I cant browse to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help: http://www.howtoforge.com/apache_subversion_repository_p2